# Alternative to Silverlight in Dynamics CRM

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

Looks like Microsoft is phasing out silverlight<sup>1</sup>, what are good alternatives to silverlight to build feature rich UIs? I suppose one could roll his own HTML web resource and javascript and interact with the Xrm API.

1: I've read on numerous places that there will not be a SilverLight 6, and no future road map for SL.

Comment: +1 vote for HTML + JS. Especially as CRM is now cross browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's going to take a while before the support for SilverLight is entirely down. However, to asnwer your question, I believe that the most appropriate course is to start focusing on custom web resources deploying HTML5 components powered by JavaScript.

Comment: if you build html web resource, how do you make them look consistent with the rest of the Dynamics controls? reverse engineer the css classes?

Comment: @sshen By the magic of CSS's keywords such as *background* and *fon-face*.   :)

Comment: I would also add: html5 + **jQuery** is quite a nice alternative to Silverlight.

Comment: Since there is no way to send an e-mail, I'll use this, your reputation along with mine (although yours much worse than mine), took a serious nose dive...

Answer (score 1):

Choose your option carefully.
1. Silverlight Support is not ending soon, Look at the road map of the solution you are building, also consider if you'll be doing development from scratch or you have components that you can reuse.

1. Silverlight in going down because everyone is now supporting HTML5/CSS3.0/JavaScript. That is most logical alternative available to you.
2. While developing your HTML 5 component make sure you are doing in a supported manner and taking care of Cross Browser compatibility in your code as Microsoft is releasing cross browser compatible version of Dynamics CRM and you don't want your solution to break once that's out.

iPad support is already available for OnLine users.

Comment: Not quite true that iPad support is available. There are numerous issues with sales section, or instance. Also, just because MS claims that the support for SilverLight will continue, it doesn't mean jack. People are not using it because they have easier alternatives (which IMHO is a shame because I like SilverLight).